# How to capture the stacktrace and exception of a failed step

Tags: logging, python-behave

I'm new to Behave, and unfamiliar with its log capture paradigm.

When a step fails due to an exception, I need to extract the stacktrace (traceback) for custom processing.

How can I capture this information?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am not asking how to capture an *expected* exception. I am instead asking how to grab the stacktrace of a failed test.

This must be a basic feature of the Behave framework that I cannot find in the documentation. I am not looking for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Have you tried a `try` `catch` block? Is there a sample code of what you would like to catch?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Behave framework? Your comment seems pretty general.

Comment: My knowledge is very limited with the framework, but you either need to write your own wrappers and do asserts. [link]
(http://stackoverflow.com/a/27895277/1771644) 
[Docs](http://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/intro.html#select-an-assertation-matcher-library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Exceptions in Python Behave Testing framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894993/handling-exceptions-in-python-behave-testing-framework)

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace and exception are contained inside the `step` object.

```
import traceback

if step.status == "failed":

    txt_tb = u"".join(traceback.format_tb(step.exc_traceback)
    txt_ex = step.exception.message
```